# How to forget remembered option in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I chose the option to open another project in the same window, and to have IDEA remember that, but I know I want to open multiple projects in separate windows. But IDEA remembers my first choice, and I couldn't find how to undo that. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

`Settings -> General -> Confirm window to open project in`.